# Kafka Consumer multi tenancy

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to writing the Kafka consumer, I have  scenario in case I have two consumer running under a same group id and I have two partitions.

Suppose that;

**Consumer 1===>Linked to ====>Partition 1**

**Consumer 2===>Linked to ====>Partition 2**

I case my consumer-2 is down how can I ensure that my Consumer-1 re-read all the event which came to partition 2 again, I just came across some thing regarding setConsumerRebalanceListener so I have set my container property for this, and for the onPartitionsAssigned method I am setting `consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment())`

Is this correct, does this line means my consumer-1 will read all the event from partition-2 as well when the consumer-2 is down and the partition-2 is reassigned to consumer?

I also will request if someone could share some good links where i can read the basics about `ConsumerRebalanceListener`.

```
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MultiTenancyOrgDataMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        LOG.debug("ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory executing");
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MultiTenancyOrgDataMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment()); // read topic from beginning on service restart

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why do you want to re-read all messages again?

Comment: Hi I have a requirement where I need to cache the payload received by each consumer so in case 1 of the consumer goes down I want to ensure all the payload which was read/ processed by that consumer Will be read again by the active consumer and all its payload will be again cached by active consumer

Answer (score 0):

This is what committing is for - if consumer 2 goes down then any records it has consumed but not committed will be picked up by consumer 1 after a rebalance.

This is one reason that Kafka supports at least once semantics - after rebalance consumer 1 will pick up from the last committed offset and hence may process records that have been successfully processed by consumer 2 if it died before committing.

An example of why you might use a ConsumerRebalanceListener is to deal with pausing across a  rebalance - I have written about this at https://chrisg23.blogspot.com/2020/02/why-is-pausing-kafka-consumer-so.html?m=1

Comment: By the way matching number of partitions to number of consumers puts a limit on how much you.van scale - it is usually a good idea to have more partitions than consumers.

Comment: (can scale - sorry, horrible phone keyboard!)

Comment: Thanks Chris for the detail explanation...so  I have a requirement where I need to cache the payload received by each consumer so in case 1 of the consumer goes down I want to ensure all the payload which was read/ processed by that consumer Will be read again by the active consumer and all its payload will be again cached by active consumer. ..so am doing a manual acknowledgement here so not sure how to ensure I meet the requirements her

Comment: Hmm - suggests you need a central cache, else you essentially have to ensure that all nodes have a complete copy of the history of messages - that's a very complex problem. Is it an in-memory cache? If so, can you just have an instance of Redis shared by all consumers, with a bit of duplicate detection for messages consumed more than once?

Comment: Though it is probably worth stepping back and looking at what your requirement is without a specific solution in mind. I'm not convinced that managing separate caches and seeking back is the best approach - what if there is patching and all consumers are restarted one after the other, also are you sure all messages are being retained indefinitely on the brokers? And if they are over time the catch up following a rebalance will become more and more onerous.